# Can't query realm result correctly by NSDate property

Tags: realm

I want to query realm results by predicate, but predicate is wrong when i use NSDate property as params.

I use Xcode 10.3, the newest realm SDK.

```
+ (NSArray *)getBookingListFromDBWithStartTime:(NSDate *)startTime endTime:(NSDate *)endTime
{
   NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"rez_time >= %@ AND rez_time < %@", startTime, endTime];
   RLMResults<CDRealmBookingModel *> *sessionArray = [CDRealmBookingModel objectsWithPredicate:pred];
   //Printing description of pred: rez_time >= CAST(589885200.000000,"NSDate") AND rez_time < CAST(589917600.000000, "NSDate")
   //Printing description of startTime: 2019-09-11 09:00:00 +0000
}
```

I tried to unify the NSDate format of in and out value to realmL. ike "YYYYMMddHHmmssSSS". But still can't query results.

Comment: There is result in realm file. I can see it with Realm Browser.

Comment: Realm fully supports filtering by NSDates so it's not really clear what the issue is. This also looks like objc so you may want to add that tag. Perhaps the startTime and endTimes do not have a match in the database. Have you printed them both out to check the actual dates you are querying for and see if there are items in your database that fall within that range?

Comment: Yes, i've printed the all results and it's no problem. I guess realm cant query with one filed twice?  `rez_time >= %@ AND rez_time < %@`

Comment: Yes. You can query like that to create a range. I did a Swift version of your code and it works just fine. NSDate or Swift Date queries are fully supported so it's unclear what the issue is. See [Filtering](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#queries) noting that <, > AND and BETWEEN are supported on NSDates. As mentioned above, even though you have data in your Realm, perhaps it doesn't match the dates presented in the query you are running. Did you try to run the query with no filter to see if any data loads?

Comment: Yes, if i run the query with no filter can load all data. I still can't find why the filter code don't work. So i just load all the data and filt by Objective-C again. It's clumsy.

Comment: The code appears to work for me. Can you include your Realm model in the question?